# Magento 1.9 - Load external script async the right way

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, javascript, xml

How can I load external scripts `async` (and preferably also `defer`). I know I can add attributes to local scripts like this:

```
<action method="addJs"><script>js/script.js</script><params>async defer</params></action>
```

But how do I load external scripts? The method above does not work for external scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't natively you must use a third party Module, you can try this

http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-external-javascript-css-file-to-magento/

Comment: Git repo here: https://github.com/netzkollektiv/Magento_InchooXternal

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from layout XML, but it is basically the same as placing it directly into your block.  Here's an example:

```
<block type="core/text" name="block_name">
   <action method="setText">
      <text>
         <![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js" async="async"></script>]]>
      </text>
   </action>
</block>
```

Comment: Only disadvantage is the script is written after all script/css link hrefs.

Comment: @Earlee - If you place it in a `<reference name="head">` wrapper as @Devtype did, it should load (asyncronously) at the same time as the others in your `<head>` tag, but depending on where you place it in the xml, it may be added before or after others.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by below code (which isn't different from your code tbf). Tested and it works:

```
<reference name="head">
<action method="addJs"><script>https://api.xyz.com/xyz.js</script><params>async defer</params></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: In version 1.9.x, it will not work as it will be padded with your domain. so that will become `https://yourshop.com/js/https://api.xyz.com/xyz.js` and result in 404.